# Debug output showing in Laravel api

Tags: php, api, symfony, laravel, laravel-5

Using Laravel 5.1 and dingo/api with Fractal.

I am throwing an exception using HttpException and expect to see both my http status code and my message, however I am also getting debug output.

```
if ($paginator->total() == 0)
        {
            throw new \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException('404', 'No properties found');
        }
```

Gives me the following output:-

```
{
  "message": "No properties found",
  "status_code": "404",
  "debug": {
    "line": 203,
    "file": "C:\\\\xampp\\\\htdocs\\\\laravel\\\\apiv3\\\\app\\\\Http\\\\Controllers\\\\api\\\\v1\\\\SearchController.php",
    "class": "Symfony\\\\Component\\\\HttpKernel\\\\Exception\\\\HttpException",
    "trace": [
      "#0 [internal function]: App\\\\Http\\\\Controllers\\\\Api\\\\v1\\\\SearchController->search()",
      "#1 C:\\\\xampp\\\\htdocs\\\\laravel\\\\apiv3\\\\vendor\\\\laravel\\\\framework\\\\src\\\\Illuminate\\\\Routing\\\\Controller.php(256): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)",
```

etc.

I have tried to turn off debug in my .env file, but it has no effect. I want to be able to turn debug code on or off. I'm sure its' something simple I'm missing.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a key API_DEBUG in your .env, set it to false.

Answer (score 0):

I think, in your `config/app.php` debug may set to `true`, change it to `false`

Comment: No, Laravel5.1 uses .env and it's set to false.

Comment: Ok, in `config/app.php` there should be `'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG'),`, that refers to .env. May be it changed, just check it there

Comment: Thanks, but debug is false in .env.  APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=false and in config/app.php it is 'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG'),